# Aplicativos iOS feitos em Phonegap podem ser compilados no Windows?

Tags: ios, apache-cordova, phonegap-buillder

O Phonegap builder serve apara compilar os aplicativos para você, porém no iOS dá erro ao compilar. O que é preciso para compilar no iOS utilizando o Phonegap builder? Que tipo de chave é preciso para compilá-lo?

Eu achei este link do phonegap: http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/signing_signing-ios.md.html

Alguém poderia colocar de maneira mais clara como compilar app em iOS utilizando Windows?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trabalho profissionalmente com Phonegap, então posso responder esta pergunta pra você.

**Não é possível fazer isso sem um Mac.**

**Mas por que?**

O Phonegap usa o conceito de webview. Ele cria uma estritura padrão de diretórios e nós desenvolvemos normalmente como se fosse uma página resposiva. O Phonegap se responsabiliza de criar o projeto para a plataforma em questão, de distribuir todos os fontes que nós escrevemos e plugins e de realizar o build/deploy do projeto para uma plataforma específica.

O build não é mágico, ele simplesmente utiliza o sdk que já deve estar devidamente instalado no computador. No seu caso, para fazer o build de um projeto iOs é necessário ter a SDK da Apple (XCode), que só roda no MAC.

Por isso que não é possível fazer um projeto iOS no windows.

Apenas para informação, existem soluções que permitem buildar um app iOS no windows, mas essas soluções ainda sim dependem de um mac como servidor. Estou falando do Xamarin.

Comment: Edgar só uma dúvida, é possível usar um HACKINTOSH em uma vm para fazer uma build de um projeto iOS?

Comment: @haykou Eu nunca tentei. O Hackintosh além de não ser uma ferramenta oficial, instala-lo é uma tarefa árdua. Nunca conheci alguém que conseguiu desenvolver profissionalmente usando o hackintosh, mas se você tiver uma vm funcionando no seu pc você pode tentar instalar o xcode.

Comment: Muito boa a resposta, você poderia colocar mais informações sobre o Xamarin? Não tem problema que quem faz a compilação é um servidor mac, dês que dê para compilar sem ter um um Mac.

Comment: @FelipeJorge Eu nunca usei o Xamarim, só conheço de nome mesmo. Um dos motivos de eu nunca ter usado é que ele custa caro, acho mais jogo comprar um Mac usado mesmo...

Comment: Eu consegui compilar no Windows. Gerei o arquivo e baixei pelo iTunes pro meu Iphone para testá-lo. Foi bem chato o processo e infelizmente eu não documentei. Inclusive eu mesmo parei o meu projeto por preguiça de repetir o processo, pois quando tentei de novo gerar, algum certificado expirou e não compilou. Mas esses dias pretendo parar e refazer tudo com calma e posto aqui a solução. Tive que fazer varias coisas através de linha de comando, acho que era justamente para gerar os arquivos usando um Servidor Mac por ai.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo estes passos que você utilizou estão descritos passo-a-passo no site do Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

Cara até onde eu sei essa chave que você precisa para compilar seu aplicativo para ios, só é possível gerar através do MAC OS X. Mas dê uma lida nesse artigo, talvez te ajude http://www.loiane.com/2013/01/como-se-tornar-um-desenvolvedor-ios-certificado-pela-apple-se-inscrever-no-ios-developer-program-sem-fax/.